# Best route around confirmed appts - Traveling Salesman Problem

Tags: traveling-salesman, routing

First, I am not a programmer, but an end user.  We are trying to come up with a solution to a TSP issue that is causing us SIGNIFICANT time being wasted "manually" routing.

Here is the issue.  We receive customers to go see.

We route, place on the calendar and confirm about 50% of the appointments before more customers come in that need to be added into the route, placed on the calendar and called to confirm.

We are having a hard time automating the routing process after part of the customers are confirmed and new ones come in.  We currently manually create the route which takes a lot of wasted time.

Any suggestions?  Keep in mind, that I am not a programmer but the end user who is desperate to get a solution.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think your question is a good fit for a site which "is for students, researchers and practitioners of computer science" - given that you do not fit that audience. We are likely to recommend specific techniques and algorithms for solving TSP, but you are likely looking for a piece of software that is ready to go. It might be better suited to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. Your question is very open-ended (there are very many well-documented, well-known approaches to solving TSP - why do those not work for you? What do you need specifically?).

Comment: @TomvanderZanden Actually, I think it's a decent fit. The question is, in CS terms, "What good algorithms exist for online TSP."  (To the asker, "online" in this context has nothing to do with the internet but means that the data arrives as you're trying to compute the answer.)

Comment: What's wrong with running any standard, existing heuristic or approximation algorithm for TSP, as each customer arrives, and re-doing it each time a new customer arrives?  There are many such algorithms documented in the literature.  Which ones have you tried?  What research have you done?  We expect you to do significant research on your own before asking and to show us in the question what you've tried.

Comment: I was not able to find any TSP code which included re-routing for the most efficient route around an appointment that was confirmed.  So, I wrote out the logic that I used in my head and gave it to our programmers and it works perfect now.  I appreciate the information on softwarerecs and look forward to using it!  It is always better to integrate instead of recreate!